# Make File appear like a Folder

Tags: windows, filesystems, conversion, shared-folders

So here's the scenario. My company's network has a "dropbox" (aka scratch drive) on the network which we can use to temporarily store our files. However, IT can choose to, on any given night, delete all the files on the drive (like most scratch drives). However, I noticed that whatever script they are using to  traverse the directory tree and delete the files, preserves folder structure, regardless of who created the folder.

So the question is, if I want to keep some file on the drive at all times, can I somehow make the file appear to the system/script as a folder would. I am assuming the server is a windows server box.

Things I've tried:

- Renaming the file to a *.FOLDER extension - DOES NOT WORK
- Renaming the file to a *.fpbf extension - In Test
- Renaming the file to a *.tsf extension - In Test

Notes:

1. The .FOLDER idea was just a shot in the dark. It even says [here](http://filext.com/file-extension/FOLDER) that it won't  work because "Windows doesn't work that way".
2. the fpbf and tsf extensions are something I saw [here](http://www.instructables.com/answers/Convert-File-to-Folder/), though it probably has a 0.00001% chance of working

My thinking is, if I can make a file appear to the system like a folder, I can take any directory tree, zip it, "convert" it into a file, and preserve all the data from being deleted.

I understand this should really not be done, and that there might be better ways to go about it, but I am more asking if it is **possible**, not if this is the recommended course of action.

Comment: If you have something "super important" I would recommend finding somewhere else to store it, rather than relying on the current implementation of the IT dept's script.  Maybe talk to IT and have them setup a dedicated place for your important data.

Comment: @heavyd Agreed. Maybe "super important" was a bad descriptor, but it's a database file I need to host for other people to access. We already asked IT to make it permanent, or to give us a permanent location, but they flat out said no :(

Comment: If IT says no (when you ask) then I think your only recourse is to ask your manager to make the request up the chain.

Comment: @dberm22 - You should then go to your project manager and request the resources or equipment or authorization to do what your doing.  We would need their script to even begin to understand what they are doing.

Comment: I work for a very big, very security-minded company, and my manager, and my manager's manager, and his manager have been fighting for over a year to get this dev network set up. They have VERY tight constraints, and this is the setup that has been approved by our customer. Any change will have a years worth of paperwork attached, and they are not willing to budge. I agree this is a worst case scenario. I'm not really asking IF I should do it, I'm more asking if it's POSSIBLE to do. Thanks for your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not sure if this is a company-specific implementation thing or an OS hack, but renaming the file to a `*.FLD` extension does the trick. Also, surprisingly, a `*.File folder` yes "File folder", works as well. It doesn't really look to the user like a folder, but it apparently gets skipped by my company's folder filter.